# Django - ForeignKey "Reverse" ("_set")

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I need to cruise back in reverse through my Foreignkey. For some reason it doesn't work...

models.by :

```
class Investment(models.Model):
 feeder = models.ForeignKey(Fund, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 investor = models.ForeignKey(Investor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

(...)

```
class Fund(models.Model):
 slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = 'default')
```

(...)

```
class Investor(models.Model):
 account = models.CharField(max_length = 10, unique=True)
 first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

(...)
views.py :

```
Investment.objects.filter(investor__pk=pk)
```

--> I need to get to the slug attribute of Fiund of each Investment of an investor.. I have already filtered on investor (that's ok). Next is cruising to the slug. I assume I need to work with fund.set_all() but it doesn't work.. Anyone to the rescue?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused by how this works. To work your way from Investor -> Funds, you would have to go through Investor -> Investment -> Funds. You can do this like so:

First, use `related_name`:

```
class Investment(models.Model):
    feeder = models.ForeignKey(Fund, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="investmentAsFeeder")
     investor = models.ForeignKey(Investor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="investmentAsInvestor")
```

Then, you can use it like so:

```
investor = Investor.objects.get(id=1)
investors_investments = investor.investmentAsInvestor.all()
investor_investment_funds = Fund.objects.filter(investmentAsFeeder__in=investor_investments)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need values only you can get it with one query:

```
my_investor = Investor.objects.get(pk=pk)
my_investor.invesment_set.values('id', 'feeder__slug`)
```

Or you can have another query if you don't need investor instance itself:

```
Investment.objects.filter(investor__pk=pk).values('id', 'feeder__slug')
```